# Exception code 0xe0434352 that crashes w3wp.exe | dotnet run

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I find out that an error on my server was crashing the server and not being handled by global exception handler.
I am not totally sure that what I will describe is the same problem that I am having (using 3rd party libs, plus custom logic in the middle... is difficult to analyze the full code), although I suspect that is the same.

- Can anyone explain me why the global exception handler cannot handle exceptions raised after start writing the response?
- And if is something we can do about this?

I am using ASP.Net core 3.0

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(options => options.Run(HandleException));

        app.Map("/map1", HandleMapTest1);
        app.Map("/map2", HandleMapTest2);
    }

    private Task HandleException(HttpContext context) {
        try
        {
            var exceptionFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
            Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception");
        }
        catch { /*ignore*/ }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static void HandleMapTest1(IApplicationBuilder app) {
        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            throw new System.Exception("It will be caught by HandleException");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Map Test 1");
        });
    }

    private static void HandleMapTest2(IApplicationBuilder app) {
        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            var x = new MyClass();
            x.DoDSomething();
        });
    }
}

class MyListener
{
    public void Check(Action<int> action) {
        action(1);
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public MyListener DoDSomething() {
        var x = new MyListener();
        x.Check(EnterFieldNode);
        return x;

        async void EnterFieldNode(int num) => await Validate();
    }

    private async Task Validate() {
        // do something that explodes
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

I have found out [this article](https://stackify.com/csharp-catch-all-exceptions/), that uses the UnhandledException event from the AppDomain to catch the exception, although is not possible (at least in a straightforward way) to avoid the server crash.

---

**UPDATE 1:** Example updated. Finally was able to reproduce. The code is the most similar possible to what is happening with a 3rd party library that I am using. It crashes the w3p process and I got a error in event viewer with Exception code 0xe0434352.

Comment: The first thing the exception-handler middleware does once it detects an exception is check whether the response has already been sent. If it has, it just rethrows the exception. See the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/3.0/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L94).

Comment: ok effectively dotnet run shows the exception but doesn't crash. But if I run with debugger, the debug session stops. Although the global exception handler doesn't catch the exception, why? I saw the dotnet core that checks if the response has already been sent, and bubbles up the exception. Why? Why doesn't the global exception handler?

Comment: Scanning your code sample, if your server is crashing it's likely because of your aync void - https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely because of `async void`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin but am I doing something wrong in that code, or could potentially be a bug in CLR?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#async-void).

Answer (score 1):

As @KirkLarkin mentioned above in the comments, the `async void` is the problem. Here's some links with more details:

[Async Guidance](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#async-void)

[TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)